# Sharing QGIS Project with PostGIS connection

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am trying to share a QGIS project with multiple people which accesses a PostGIS database. Is there a relatively simple way to do this? How can I make sure that they are able to access the database?

Edit: If I share a QGIS project with a few users outside my network, will they be able to access the project if the project connects to a local PostGIS database on my computer, or will I somehow have to provide them access to the database? I am new to QGIS and could use some help. I have read some posts about editing the pg_hba.conf file, using GeoGig, or using AWS to host the database, but I am still confused as to which approach to take and why.

Comment: Can you add more info? Are people ALL within your organization? Do you care about security if the password is in the project file, or do you want to keep the password on computer only? Anyway, I recommand the use of a PostgreSQL service file if it's possible.

Comment: Thanks, the users are all within my organization and security is not of huge importance.

Comment: please add more details

Comment: "Outside my network" and "within my organization" conflict. If users don't have network connectivity to the database, they aren't really users.

Comment: You need to provide them access to your database. Otherwise they can view the project, but no connected data. Best way would be to setup a server (or use a service) and move your local database over there.